# why the total task number get bigger and bigger?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

[image]

I'm using spark streaming to read data from kafka.

why the total task number get bigger and bigger? after several days' running, I'm afraid it will exceed 2 billion... and maybe the counter will overflow? Does your spark streaming jobs have this phenomenon, too?

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is simply because your **consumer is as fast as the producer**, so as the time going, more and more tasks are accumulated for further consumption.

It may due to your Spark cluster's incapacity to process such a large batch.

It may also be related the **checkpoint interval time**, maybe you are setting it too large or too small.

It may also be related to your settings of **Parallelism**, **Partitions** or **Data Locality** etc.

-----add on------

I just also found that the parameter **spark.streaming.blockInterval** is also very important. By default it's 0.5 seconds, i.e. create one task every 0.5 seconds.

So maybe you can try to increase the **spark.streaming.blockInterval** to be 5s or 10s, to see if there is a improve. good luck

Read this

> [Tuning Spark Streaming for Throughput](http://www.virdata.com/tuning-spark/)

.

> [How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs (Part 1)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/)

.

> [How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs (Part 2)](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each kafka message is processed as a seperate task. This is the nature of spark streaming.

I have faced the similar issue.

Just repartition the RDD after reading the Kafka messages.

Then no of tasks will be under control.